# Pandas merge dataframes by column with array value

Tags: pandas, database

I've got the following problem:
I have to dataframes A and B, where columns "_2" in the A and column "1": in the B look like:

| Column |
| --- |
| np.array() |
| np.array() |

These two dataframes have other column also. I want to merge them by column "_2" and "1"

I am using

```
pd.merge(A, B, left_on='_2', right_on=1)
```

and get the next error:

```
unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because pandas is not able to hash the arrays to compare them and merge those rows.

Maybe we would need to understand more about the use case to propose a solution. Why do you need to merge these dataframes using array columns? Are you able to merge using other columns? Are you able to parse these array into simpler types (int, string)?

Comment: I am able to parse these arrays somehow to strings and I haven't other columns to merge by

Comment: In that case maybe you can try parsing the arrays to strings and merge by those string columns